# .htaccess - Prevent file from inheriting Redirect rules from parent

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My site is structured like this:

```
include
include/interface/
include/templates/
include/subdomains/

include/subdomains/forum ...
```

I want to redirect the user to a 404 error when they view the fodler include and all subdirectories beyond this. This works very well, and the subdomains will view through the official forums.example.org but not through example.org/include/subdomains/forum/

To achieve this I use the rule:

```
Redirect 404 /include/
```

However, when I visit the forum and use rewritten URLs from the forum they give an error 404 because of how the forum is structured. The forum is structured like this:

include/rewrite.php

It's trying to require that file, but because of (what I'm assuming is the parent .htaccess file intefering with the forums htaccess file, it's not working and I'm getting a "The requested URL .. canot be found on this server" error.

My question is, how can I keep the parent htaccess file redirecting the site's include folder to an error, but not the one for the forum?

My code is as below:

parent htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500
ErrorDocument 501 /errors/501
ErrorDocument 502 /errors/502
ErrorDocument 503 /errors/503
ErrorDocument 504 /errors/504
ErrorDocument 505 /errors/505
ErrorDocument 506 /errors/506
ErrorDocument 507 /errors/507
ErrorDocument 508 /errors/508
ErrorDocument 509 /errors/509
ErrorDocument 510 /errors/510

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

Redirect 404 include/
```

Forum htaccess:

```
# MultiViews INTERFERS WITH PROPER REWRITING.
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# UNCOMMENT AND PROPERLY SET THE RewriteBase IF THE REWRITE RULES ARE NOT WORKING PROPERLY.
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . include/rewrite.php [L]

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# DISABLE DIRECTORY BROWSING.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# UTF-8 ENCODING.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# USE UTF-8 ENCODING FOR ANYTHING SERVED text/plain OR text/html.
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# FORCE UTF-8 FOR A NUMBER OF FILE FORMATS.
AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .js .xml .json .rss

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# BETTER WEBSITE EXPERIENCE FOR INTERNET EXPLORER USERS.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        BrowserMatch MSIE ie
        Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # BECAUSE X-UA-Compatible ISN'T SENT TO NON-IE (TO SAVE HEADER BYTES), WE NEED TO INFORM PROXIES THAT CONTENT CHANGES BASED ON UA.
    Header append Vary User-Agent
    # CACHE CONTROL IS SET ONLY IF mod_headers IS ENABLED, SO THAT'S UNNECESSARY TO DECLARE.
</IfModule>
```